# macros in excel showing error

Tags: excel, macros

```
Sub Month_Update()
    Dim dDate As Date
    dDate = Range("$C$1").Value
    Range("$E$1").Value = _
    DateSerial(Year(dDate), _
    Month(dDate) + 1, Day(dDate))
End Sub
```

Run time error: 13
Type mismatch

Answer (score 0):

You may be having an issue with the module accessing data on another sheet. Try the following to specify the exact sheet that you would like to pull from:

```
Sub Month_Update()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Excel.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Replace This Sheet1 Value with the Name of the Sheet that the data is on
    Dim dDate As Date
    dDate = ws.Range("$D$1").Value
    ws.Range("$E$1").Value = _
    DateSerial(Year(dDate), _
    Month(dDate) + 1, Day(dDate))
End Sub
```

Comment: Using 2016/5/2
as value in cell C1

Comment: I just tried it using the date you sent and everything works fine. How are you entering data in Cell C1

Comment: "Info Collecting
Date" "Payment Notice
Issue Date" "Salary
Distribution Date"
2016/5/2 2016/5/3 2016/5/5
2016/5/4 2016/5/6 2016/5/10

Sub Month_Update()
    Dim dDate As Date
    dDate = Range("$D$1").Value
    Range("$F$1").Value = _
    DateSerial(Year(dDate), _
    Month(dDate) + 1, Day(dDate))
End Sub

Still getting Run time error 13: Type mismatch

Comment: All I want to do is change the date to next month automatically. Please help :)

Comment: Try using the new code i posted. and replace the "Sheet1" value with the name of the sheet that the data is on.

Comment: Hi @Tyler,      

It still says Type Mismatch :(

Comment: @ Vas - Debug your code to see where the issue is. Looks like the issue is adding 1 to month(dDate). if you are adding 1 to a string, it will throw type mismatch error

Comment: @ Vas - Set the format of the date cells to 'yyyy-mm-dd' before adding 1 to the month